# Authentication issue with Default Credentials

Tags: sonarqube

As a first time user ,I am not able to login with default credentials i.e. admin/admin but i can access page on http://localhost:9000/

Version -6.6
Windows 2016

I will appreciate if anyone can help me in this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any errors in the files in _$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs_

Comment: Without any log it's indeed impossible to help you

Comment: Did you execute an upgrade or use SonarQube for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your JDK version. I am using sonarqube 6.4 and sonarqube was not authenticating with admin/admin as it was incorrectly using JDK 9 to start.

Once I started it with JDK 8 it connected with the admin/admin credentials.

In the file sonarqube-6.4\conf\wrapper.conf
Add the below path to java.exe against "wrapper.java.command" property.
`wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java`